# How to determine the cause of `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'`

Tags: python, optimization

I am doing the optimize but I got a wrong error(`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'`).

I have a couple of known arguments (Jflu, Ci, Rd, O, A) in the excel. I import these parameters from excel using Pandas first. `g` is an unknown constant, I want to get an optimal `g` to make the `objfun` minimize.

I am new to Python. My code is as follows:

```
#import my data 
import pandas as pd
curves=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Hello World/Curves.xlsx')
j=curves.Jflu
c=curves.Ci
R=curves.Rd
O=curves.O
A=curves.A

# optimize data
from scipy.optimize import minimize
#objective function
def objfun(g):
    return (-(j/g+4.0*c+8.0*O-4.0*R/g)-((j/g+4.0*c+8.0*O-4.0*R/g)**2.0-4.0*(-4.0/g)*(8.0*O*R+4.0*c*R+O*j-c*j))**0.5)/(2.0*(-4.0/g))-A

g0=[0.001]
print(objfun(g0))

#Bounds
bnds=((0,1.0),)

#Minimize the function
res=minimize(objfun,g0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds)
print (res)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g0=[0.001]
print(objfun(g0))
```

`g0` is a list containing a single integer. You pass this to a function which uses it (the list) for a division. Defining g0 as `g0 = 0.001` should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you call `objfun(g0)`, you're passing in a list. `g0` was defined as a list when it was declared as `g0 = [0.001]`. You can:

- Declare it as a non-list variable: `g0 = 0.001`

  - Do this if you meant to pass in a single value every time.
- Make your function use the value in your list: `return (-(j/g[0]+4.0*c+8.0*O-4.0*R/g[0])-((j/g[0]+4.0*c+8.0*O-4.0*R/g[0])**2.0-4.0*(-4.0/g[0])*(8.0*O*R+4.0*c*R+O*j-c*j))**0.5)/(2.0*(-4.0/g[0]))-A`

  - Do this if you plan to expand the code to process a list - `g[0]` would become `g[i]`, assuming you have a for loop counting `i` from `0` to `len(g)` and aren't using a ranged for loop.

Comment: "Declare it as an int: g0 = 0.001" That most definitely is not an `int` :)